# Which HTML tag will be appropriate for the article abstract?

Tags: html, seo, accessibility

Which HTML tag will be the best for the red part in HTML case?

[image]

AFAIK the **summary** tag has another concept - it consists from the short text and details which could be hidden (collapsed). In the case of the article, basically it is nothing required to hide./

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic HTML and ARIA do not express much of the semantics of scholarly publications.

But the W3C recommendation "[Digital Publishing WAI-ARIA Module 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/dpub-aria-1.0/)" includes a "[doc-abstract](https://www.w3.org/TR/dpub-aria-1.0/#doc-abstract)" ARIA role that represents abstracts like the one in your example. There is also a [proposal](https://w3c.github.io/scholarly-html/) for using this and other standards in scholarly publications. Starting with conventional HTML as proposed by Ilan Edri and adding such specialized markup can improve discovery and interpretation of your content by users of current and future technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<h>` tag for the "Abstract" word, and `<p>` tag for the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please to say how this abstract will stand out from the remain text for the SEO and screen reader? Only by "Abstract" word inside the **h2** tag?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understood your question.
SEO has basic rules which means you have to use h1,h2,h3, and h4 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jonathan’s interesting answer and some research, I’d would recommend `<aside>` and `<meta name="description">` in the head.

```html
<aside aria-labelledby="h-abstract">
  <h2 id="h-abstract">Abstract</h2>
```

`<aside>` has [the `complementary` ARIA role](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#complementary). Its definition says

> […] The contents of a complementary landmark would be expected to remain meaningful if it were to be separated from the main content it is relevant to.

That compares very well to what [*Abstract* on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_(summary)), states:

> An abstract may act as a stand-alone entity instead of a full paper.

And finally, `<meta name="description">` *will* be used instead of the full paper on search engines or when sharing the page.

[ARIA Digital Publishing’s `doc-abstract` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/dpub-aria-1.0/#doc-abstract) naturally has the most appropriate definition.

> A short summary of the principle ideas, concepts and conclusions of the work, or of a section or excerpt within it.

In the publishing standard, it’s a subclass of `section`, just as `complementary` is.